# Org mode - capture - .emacs problem

Tags: org-mode

Today I went to the EMACS org wiki http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-up-capture.html#Setting-up-capture

and copy/pasted this directly into my .emacs file

```
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
     (define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

Now I'm getting this:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   ‘/home/kantuck/.emacs’:
>
> Symbol's value as variable is void: org-directory
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.

I also tried a fresh .emacs file in case of conflicts, and put only that into it, and still it's giving me that error.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 7):

Is `org-directory` a valid variable? You can check that with <kbd>C-h v org-directory</kbd>.

My emacs reports it as

> org-directory is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

So you need to load org to get the variable defined. Before your lines above, add this:

```
(require 'org)
```

Comment: You can also have your configuration applied lazily whenever `org` is actually loaded by wrapping your config lines in a `(with-eval-after-load  'org ...)` form.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My apologies for so late a reply. I don't know what happened, but that line was ;; out for some reason in my .emacs file. Even the /old one/ I've been trying to fix another problem and was copy/pasting parts back into a new one.

I took out the ;;, and it works like a charm. Very odd, but this is computers :)

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it working.